# Python Bot that fills the form on API call

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest, automation

I am looking for a best way to do this/guidance. I made a python bot that clicks around the website and fills in the form, and submits the form at the end. All values passed in the form are hard coded into the bot.

So, what I need to do is, that when someone sends an API call containing the data I need to pass in form in raw JSON, for example:

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "5876521548", 
    "start_date": "22032021",
    "end_date": "15062021" 
}]}
```

I need some kind of a RESTapi or service (idk I am new at this) that will take that API call, pass the values into my python bot script, and start my bot, returning a message that everything went fine.

Comment: Well you can use nginx+php or node.js  and execute your bot script with command line parameters from the php page.

Comment: @BijayRegmi Can you elaborate a bit on this please? I am new to all of this.

Comment: Well to receive api requests, you need a webserver, for that you can use nginx and you can set up php page that takes POST requests with variables, and uses php's `exec()` command to run your script that you have written to fill the form. For me to give you clear instructions I would need your operating system, and whether you have admin permissions to install software on your machine.

Comment: Alternatively you could use sockets to transfer data but then it gets really complicated to connect to it etc.

Comment: @BijayRegmi the OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and I do have permission to install software on the machine. Anything else I can provide you with?

Comment: But you do not have a webserver installed on it?

Comment: @BijayRegmi how do I check if I do?

Comment: what happens if you type `http://<ip-of-machine>` in your browser?

Comment: @BijayRegmi I get The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer\u2019s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: can you ssh into the machine and type `netstat -tulpn | grep "80"` if you see your machine listening to port 80 or 443, you probably have a webserver installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Flask. Flask is a web framework that is typically used for web development. It is perfect for taking an existing Python script and turning it into an API.

Here's a simple example that I found with a bit of googling:

https://dev.to/aaahmedaa/create-restapi-for-your-python-scripts-using-flask-with-15-line-of-code-10ml